# Firestore: Move documents from one path to another using batch writes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to move about 1600 firestore documents from one path location say collection A to another location say collection B. What's the best optimal way to do this migration using batch writes.Assuming I also have sub-collections inside the collection(A), Is it also possible to move only the documents without the sub-collections?
Here's my sample code. Running this code returns error: **"14 UNAVAILABLE: 413:Request Entity Too Large"**

```
 
const migrateData = async (fromPath, toPath) => {
  try {
    const fromPathSnapshot = await firestore.collection(fromPath).get()
    let batch = firestore.batch()

    fromPathSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const newDocRef = firestore.collection(toPath).doc(doc.id);
      console.log('Migrating doc: ' + doc.id)
      batch.set(newDocRef, doc.data(), { merge: false });

      const oldDocRef = firestore.collection(fromPath).doc(doc.id)
      console.log('Deleting doc: ' + doc.id)
      batch.delete(oldDocRef)
    });
    await batch.commit();
    console.log('Migration successful')
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(`Something went wrong: ${error.message}`);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch writes are limited to 500 documents per batch.  According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Each transaction or batch of writes can write to a maximum of 500 documents. For additional limits related to writes, see [Quotas and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions).

It sounds like you are exceeding that limit.  You will have to break this up into individual batches and commit them individually in order to observe that limit.